# AddThis Not Working in Angular 6/7 Project

Tags: angular, addthis

Working on an Angular 6/7 site where AddThis is required to share pages.  For starters, set up a simple HTML page as follows:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <div>AddThis below</div>
    <div class="addthis_toolbox addthis_default_style addthis_32x32_style">
        <a class="addthis_button_facebook"></a>
        <a class="addthis_button_twitter"></a>
        <a class="addthis_button_email"></a>
        <a class="addthis_button_linkedin"></a>
        <a class="addthis_button_compact"></a>
    </div>
    <div>AddThis above</div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://s7.addthis.com/js/300/addthis_widget.js#pubid=ra-5c2bf6b040727c90" async="async"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

This works and displays buttons as expected.

Then tried to move it into Angular.  Set up a simple component to hold the HTML.  Tried putting the script tag into index.html.  Also tried it in the component.  In no case was I able to get it to display anything.

Set up a StackBlitz [angular-addthis](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-addthis)

Then consulted with AddThis tech support. They indicated I might have to run a method (addthis.layers.refresh()) to refresh after routing ... but it never gets that far.  Nothing displays.

In the StackBlitz, the AddThis code is app.component.  The test HTML is in standalone.html.

Any ideas appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you can't call **HTTP** scripts from **HTTPS** protocol to solve this problem

simply modify the script in the `index.html` to be 
`<script src="https://s7.addthis.com/js/300/addthis_widget.js#pubid=ra-5c2bf6b040727c90" async></script>`

Comment: Thanks.  Tried it but made no difference.

Comment: here is the solution https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-addthis-ehh8mx

Comment: Thanks - that stackblitz represents my work to date.  It works on one page, but in the real app there are problems after routing/navigating to different component.  The addthis:url is updated (you can see it in the inspector), but when you click on the AddThis buttons, the url is the same as before routing.  The approach is supposed to be to run addthis.layers.refresh(), but message is that it's not defined ... still trying to work through it.